# Communication with kernel without shell

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am using a linux from past few months, and this doubt flashed.
Is it possible to communicate with linux kernel without using any shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can communicate with Linux kernel from your code directly through the [syscall](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscall.2.html) function, see also [sycalls](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). However these are seldom used directly, most often they are called through the wrapper functions from [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/).

Comment: In particular, you don't need any shell. A kernel is starting the `/sbin/init` program (which usually is not a shell today) and that `init` program could start other programs (with `fork`, `execve` ...) without any shell. A shell is just an application using system calls to start other programs. See http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ for more

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "communicate with Linux kernel".

You could easily write a program that reads/writes device nodes, or calls `ioctl`s on them, or what have you, and then write the program -- in which case, the program is communicating with the kernel without a shell.  If you want to be able to interactively use the system, then you are going to need some tool to interface with the filesystem and the device nodes the kernel creates, and that tool is the shell.